# Access Object Attributes using Symbols

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have this helper that I am building:

```
def myhelper(object, attributes = [])
  attributes.each do |attr|
    object.attr
  end
end
```

I invoke this helper using:

```
myhelper Person, [:title, :name]
```

What I am trying to achieve is to print a list of attributes in Person dynamically but object.attr in myhelper method won't work.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try `object.send(attr)`

Also, do you want to do a map instead?

Comment: I refined the code and used collection but send(attr) is what I needed to know. Thank you.